# "volatile const int a" vs "const volatile int a"?

Tags: c

I understood that if we use `volatile` and `const` together to a variable indicates that the variable value cannot be changed inside the scope of the code, but can be changed by outside scope — for example, hardware interaction with the variable `a`.

But what is the difference between the syntax `volatile const int a` and `const volatile int a`?

Comment: No difference whatsoever. They're all equivalent to `volatile int volatile const volatile a;` too :). See [C11 6.7.3](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.3)

Answer (score 4):

Modifier order doesn't matter when no pointers are involved. Your two examples are equivalent.

If pointers *are* involved, the order matters only relative to the name of the core type and the `*`(s). For a variable declaration with placeholders for modifiers A, B, C and D:

```
<A> int <B> * <C> * <D>
```

location `A` *or* `B` modifies the `int` (`int const` and `const int` mean the same thing), while location `C` affects the first `*` (the second level of indirection), and location `D` affects the second `*` (the first level of indirection).

So:

```
unsigned int * volatile * const x;
```

means that:

1. You can't reassign `x` itself (but you can reassign `*x` or `**x`)
2. `*x` is `volatile` (the compiler can't optimize out reads or writes to `*x`, and can't reorder them relative to other `volatile` accesses)
3. `**x` is `unsigned` (but neither `volatile` nor `const`, though `*x` being `volatile` will cause some aspects of `volatile` to be applied, simply because it's not allowed to cache `*x`, and therefore can't cache `**x` either; if your code explicitly cached though, e.g. `unsigned int *starxcopy = *x;`, then worked with `*starxcopy`, `*starxcopy` would be able to cache the pointed-to value, because the value itself is not `volatile`)